# Ways of deleting pointers in a vector [C++ ]

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

```
std::vector<Circle*> circles

for(int i=0; i<circles.size(); i++)    // 1
    delete circles[i];

for(auto & circle : circles)           // 2
    delete circle;

for(Circle * circle : circles)         // 3
    delete circle;

 for(Circle *& circle : circles){      // 4
    delete circle;
```

If I write it the first way, CLion IDE suggests me to use the second way so I guess they're the same. I'm not really sure why there's a reference next to auto and if any of methods 3 or 4 are correct as well? I would guess 4 is also same as 1 and 2.

Comment: FWIW, if you use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Circle>> circles`, you don't need to write any cleanup code.

Comment: 4 is the same as 2, 3 would be the same as using `auto` without &

Comment: All 4 methods are correct. Is this the answer to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completeness, there's one more way:

```
for(auto circle : circles)
    delete circle;
```

Now, *all* these ways in this example are equivalent and will do the job of deleting `circles` elements equally well.

Having a reference to a pointer doesn't matter (the reference is "unwrapped" in expressions - in technical terms an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion), in all cases the actual pointer value is passed to `delete`.

The IDE seems to be suggesting the most idiomatic way of writing a range-based for loop:

```
for(auto & elem : collection)
```

This is usually the safest form; this way if `collection` contains large objects, they will be iterated by reference, without unnecessary copying. It doesn't matter in our case as a trivial type like a pointer can be easily copied.

---

P.S. As others have noted, in modern C++ we try to avoid `new` and `delete` and use value semantics and smart pointers instead. So something simple like `std::vector<Circle> circles` could be all that's needed, or if pointers are required, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Circle>> circles`. No manual cleanup necessary in both cases.